# Definition of algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, curves, algebraic-curves

I'm doing a module on algebraic curves which follows Fulton's book and I'm very confused.

Let K be a field.
Right at the beginning of chapter 3 he defines an affine plane curve to be an equivalence class of non-constant polynomials in K[X,Y] which are related by a constant multiple to one another. So this means each curve would have a unique monic representative. Hence his definition in that chapter seems to define the curve to be the polynomial rather than the vanishing set.

However earlier in the book in chapter 1 he says a plane curve is the vanishing set of a non-constant polynomial in affine 2 space over K. This seems to be the definition I find over and over again wherever I go on the internet. I agree this is the more intuitive definition for a curve, but the problem is that so much that we define for curves in Fultons book seems to use the definition of it as the polynomial.

Let me illustrate my problem. X and X^2 are both valid polynomials in K[X,Y] and they both have the same vanishing set. But for X^2 I would conclude every point on its vanishing set is a multiple point (as both partial derivatives are zero) and for X I would conclude all points are simple points. So if I define the curve as the actual subset of affine 2 space I would conclude that whether a point is simple or not isn't well defined. You can say I could rectify this by saying the right one to do calculations with is X and not X^2 because it has the multiplicity, but Fulton's book doesn't seem to mention this at all.

The problem gets even worse for intersection numbers.

Comment: Could you format your question using mathjax and a better layout please?

Comment: Hi,  in the very begining  of chapter 3 in fulton  appear the phrase "We have seen that affine plane curves correspond to nonconstant polynomials
$F\in  k[X,Y ]$ without multiple factors, where F is determined up to multiplication. Then, the part without multiple factors is to avoid the cases that you mentioned of $x$ and $x^2$.
a nonzero constant"

Comment: But then right after what you’re quoted he says for some purposes it is useful to allow F to have multiple factors so we modify our definition slightly and then he gives the definition I’ve stated in the main post.